# What variables change the number of lightmaps

Tags: unity, performance, texture-atlas, lightmap

I need to know what changes the lightmap size.

For example what changes the lightmap from being 2*1024*1024 to 4*1024*1024 - having larger textures or having larger quads (having more models) or having more lights or does it depends on something else?

Comment: Have you messed around with the Lightmap settings? There's a field called `Lightmap Size` and another one called `Lightmap Resolution`, if you play and get used to them, you should be able to control the lightmap's size easier